# What is the 'Chat' function on my Smart Prime 6

Tags: sms, chat

I just got my new phone (Vodafone Smart Prime 6) and have a function called 'Chat' when in Message settings.

The messages sent on this chat function are shown in green (compared to the blue ones when sending a standard SMS). They also show when somebody is typing and when the message was read.

First I thought those are Google Hangouts, but I could not find them under the Hangout webpage on hangouts.google.com, which leads me to the conclusion that those are not hangout chats.

Could you tell me which service this is, and more important -> is there any chance to back up those messages (either via textfile export or as a file that can be imported to a new -same model- phone).

I am running Android 5.0.2. You can see a screen shot of that settings menu on the link underneath.

Kind regards,
Mike

[View image on imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/of3Ch.jpg)